# Scrollbar in html component in lwuit java

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I want to create chat window with textarea and textbox in `lwuit`. Textarea must capable to show smiley and coloring text. I have used `HtmlComponent` of lwuit and facing problem in scrollbar. As text content grows in size, whole screen scroll including textbox. I want only content of textarea to be scrolled.

How to solve it?

Comment: There is no textbox class in LWUIT. exactly tel me what you are used and what your problem?

Answer (score 1):

well, you can forbid scrolling for the whole form using 
`Form.setScrollable(false)`. 
Then you just set your HTMLcomponent scrollable "true" with the same method and finally put these two components (TextArea and HTMLComponent) to a different cosntraints (e.g. TextArea in BorderLayout.NORTH and HTMLComponent in BorderLayout.CENTER)